# Is a ring automorphism restricted to the invertibles the identity automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In the solution of an exercise in my algebra book, the author says:

> Given $\varphi \in \text{Aut}(\mathbb{Q}[x])$, we have that $\varphi(1)=1 \Rightarrow \varphi(a)=a$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Q}$

I really can't figure out why there is that implication, and this also made me think if is it possible to generalise the question the following way:

Given $A$ commutative ring with $1$ and $\varphi \in \text{Aut}(A)$, can we say that $\varphi_{|A^*}$ is the identity automorphism of $A^*$ (where $A^*$ is the group of the invertible elements of $A$)?

Comment: Your last conjecture is not true:  conjugation is an automorphism on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Isn't $\varphi(1)=1$ *always* true for a ring-homomorphism?

Comment: @Gae.S. yes it is always true, what the author is saying is that is always true for an automorphism $\varphi$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ that $\varphi(a)=a$ for every $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, because it is always true that $\varphi(1)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the last statement is wrong, a counterexample being complex conjugation on $\mathbb C$.

As for the implication, observe that for any $n > 0$:

$$\varphi(n) = n \cdot \varphi(1) = n.$$

From the definition of a ring homomorphism, it is easy to deduce that $\varphi(0) = 0$. Hence

$$0 = \varphi(0) = \varphi(1+(-1)) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(-1)$$

and so $\varphi(-1) = -1$. It follows that $\varphi(-n) = \varphi(n)\varphi(-1) = -n$ for any $n \geq 0$. Hence $\varphi$ is the identity on $\mathbb Z$.

Let now $\frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb Q$, where $a,b \in \mathbb Z$, $b \neq 0$. Then
$$a = \varphi(a) = \varphi(b \cdot \frac{a}{b}) = b \cdot \varphi(\frac{a}{b})$$

and so finally $\varphi(\frac{a}{b}) = \frac{a}{b}$ for every rational number $\frac{a}{b}$.